# A DataGridView cell won't convert into int when typing in it

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am filling a DataGridView with number when loading the app, and I'd like to allow the user to change the values of the table.

If the user puts anything that can't be converted to an integer, turn it into 0. Cell Empty? 0.

Its important the variable remains an integer because I want the sorting controls to sort it numerically, rather than alphabetically.

Here's the function I call for Cell Value Changed:

```
private void BossDropDataGridView_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    //If the content is empty, then put 0 in it
    if (bossDropDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value == null ||
        bossDropDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == "")
        bossDropDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = 0;

    try
    {
        bossDropDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = Convert.ToInt32(bossDropDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value);
    }
    catch
    {
        bossDropDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = 0;
    }
// Some silly debugging to see if it works:
    if (bossDropDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.GetType() != typeof(Int32))
        MessageBox.Show("I couldn't convert it to int tho. The type is " + bossDropDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.GetType().Name);
}
```

And sure enough:

[its a string...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB7vl.png)

Moreover, if I try to sort the table, the program crashes:

```
System.ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message=Object must of type int32
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Int32.CompareTo(Object value)
   at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.RowComparer.CompareObjects(Object value1, Object value2, Int32 rowIndex1, Int32 rowIndex2)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.RowArrayList.Pivot(Int32 left, Int32 center, Int32 right)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.RowArrayList.CustomQuickSort(Int32 left, Int32 right)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.RowArrayList.CustomSort(RowComparer rowComparer)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection.Sort(IComparer customComparer, Boolean ascending)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.SortInternal(IComparer comparer, DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, ListSortDirection direction)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.Sort(DataGridViewColumn dataGridViewColumn, ListSortDirection direction)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnColumnHeaderMouseClick(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at Program_name_here.Main() in Path-here\Program.cs:line 19
```

I tried to convert the variable using Convert.ToInt32(...)
But the variable is still of type String.
I expected the variable to convert its type.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I tried to change "Value" to "FormattedValue", but that didn't solve it either.

What helped, was adding the DataGridView_CellParsing event like this:

```
private void bossDropDataGridView_CellParsing(object sender, DataGridViewCellParsingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!int.TryParse(e.Value.ToString(), out int parsedValue))
    {
        // If parsing fails, set the value to 0
        e.Value = 0;
        e.ParsingApplied = true;
    }
    else
    {
        // If parsing succeeds, set the parsed value
        e.Value = parsedValue;
        e.ParsingApplied = true;
    }
}
```

Instead of relying on the CellValueChanged event, I used the CellParsing event, which occurs before the cell value is parsed and committed to the table itself, and that pretty much solved it.